# Apache 2.4.4 - compiled from source, a2ensite is missing?

Tags: linux, apache, virtualhost, linux-from-scratch

I've set up a Linux machine for web development and learning some administration skills. It's running with LFS, so everything is compiled from source and I have the latest versions for all software components: Linux 3.10.1, PHP 5.5.0, MySQL 5.6.12 and Apache 2.4.4.

My problem comes with Apache. I was going to learn a bit more on setting up and managing virtual hosts when I discovered a2ensite is missing from the installation.

This is my configuration setup (it's the same as in the BLFS book, so I'll paste it):

```
./configure --enable-layout=BLFS \
        --enable-mods-shared="all cgi" \
        --enable-mpms-shared=all \
        --with-apr=/usr/bin/apr-1-config \
        --with-apr-util=/usr/bin/apu-1-config \
        --enable-suexec=shared \
        --with-suexec-bin=/usr/lib/httpd/suexec \
        --with-suexec-docroot=/srv/www \
        --with-suexec-caller=apache \
        --with-suexec-userdir=public_html \
        --with-suexec-logfile=/var/log/httpd/suexec.log \
        --with-suexec-uidmin=100
```

Maybe I'm absolutely wrong and a2ensite doesn't come with the vanilla source, but I always thought it does. I have repeated the compilation over and over, examining the output very carefully and trying different combinations through the configure script, but no luck.

Is a2ensite out of current Apache sources or am I missing some other package?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. After browsing some web pages and forums I discovered `a2ensite` and `a2dissite` are Debian scripts, so I just have to re-create them or create an alternate way of working with virtual hosts (to avoid distro-centric ways of working).